# Best practices for connecting DBs that are in different geographical regions

Tags: sql-server-2008, best-practices, network

We are about to set up SQL Servers in different countries. We need to link them, but we don't have to have a direct link (as in linked server). In other words, they can be loosely coupled.

Is it better to connect them via a VPN and have them as linked servers, or use loose coupling via web services?

By "better", I am referring to stability.

Comment: VPN sounds better than web services .

Comment: Are VPNs generally stable?

Comment: I would say it realy depends on how you setup things , however i would never trust a web service .

Comment: I'm guessing how reliable the network is between the places is likely a factor, as I don't know how fault tolerant a linked server would be, but I know I could write it into the webservice code.

Comment: @poelinca I'm guessing you don't write web services then?

Comment: lol, Indeed sir. Remove a few comments? ;)

Comment: I bet the folks on [sf] have more expertise to answer this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VPNs are definitely more secure than web services.  As far as stability goes, as long as the VPN is set up correctly and the network doesn't go down in either location, VPNs are stable.

Comment: Out of interest, will a linked server auto-reconnect when a network drops & recovers?

Comment: @IanC - Not positive, but I think it depends on what kind of DB you are running.

Comment: it would be SQL Server 2008.